# WPF controls and margin proportional to the window size

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, layout

Currently when I making the UI, I set all the margin and size of the control to a fixed size according to the screen size. Is there some way adjust the size or margin dynamically proportionally to the screen size so there's no need to set the property in the XAML every time.

My current knowledge tells me that I could set the fixed width & height in style or template or in every layout which was used.

Answer (score 3):

I would say re-think your approach. Instead of absolutely positioning your elements using margins, use the correct panel so elements correctly re-position and stretch themselves depending on the size of the container.

There are many panels in WPF supporting different layouts for automatically laying out your elements dynamically, e.g. `StackPanel` for stacking, `WrapPanel` for wrapping, see the overview of panels here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx

e.g.

instead of:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Name:" Margin="92,320,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Text="enter your name..." Margin="124,320,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

use:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Name:" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBox Text="enter your name..." Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Then use `Margin` for giving the element space, not position, e.g. a margin of 5.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. But I what I do is set the size of my master window to be 80% of the client monitor size.

```
 public void SetPage(Page currentPage)
    {
        currentPage.Tag = this;  //Set the new page's Tag to 'this' so we can reference it from within.
        _mainFrame.Navigate(currentPage);
        double height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
        double width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;

        //set the size of the window to 80% of the client monitor
        this.Height = (80.0 / 100.0) * height;
        this.Width = (80.0 / 100.0) * width;

        WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;            
    }
```